# Assigning role to users with OAuth authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, roles, google-oauth

I'm using google OAuth for login to my web application. 
I want to assign ADMIN, USER roles. I am using tomcat 8 with Spring Boot. After logging in, I want to redirect users to specific pages based on their roles.

How can I assign roles to the users, I don't see the way to do it ?

Comment: Rearranged content. Edited title, added tag

Comment: can any one give a head start. Which configuration i need to change to assign a particular role to the user

Comment: Answered with some hints for you

Answer (score 0):

So here some hints :

1. Use a table to hold the urls corresponding to each roles
2. Use a table to hold the users, with login/password and reference to the correct role for them
3. Do you OAuth login process, and at the end get the url corresponding to the user login

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. The thing is i use google oauth for login. after o - auth from google user is assigned with ROLE_USER. How do i reassign the role based on their specific email id. One more thing how do i get email id during o - auth.

Answer (score 0):

The oAuth is used for authentication only, in your use case, the JWT will resolve your problem by setting the claims.